# Dynamic select box in AngularJS with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Following is my [PLNKR CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/ATq514K1be6oviJXIdod?p=preview)

**Problem** -

I am trying to create a dynamic label option and `textarea` like -

1. If a user selects "Work" then on clicking the "+" icon, next select
   will only contains ["Cell", "Home", "Fax"]
2. And then again selecting "Home", from the second select and clicking
   "+" icon, next select will only contains ["Cell", "Fax"] and so on.

But I am unable to do so as my first array is decrementing and no data is coming in the lower select options.

Let me know what I am doing wrong and how could I make it (suggestions are welcome too).

Answer (score 0):

Your $scope.temp has the correct number of objects. I think the problem is with the way you are constructing the new select options once the plus button is clicked. You are trying to construct the element using a jQuery constructor.

You might need to use a custom directive instead.

Comment: any help..means what are the things to include with directive construction ?

Answer (score 0):

Move `ng-click` to `<a>`, and add `ng-model="target"` to the textarea:

```
<select ng-model="contact"
        ng-options="selOption.value as selOption.name for selOption in selOptions"
        ng-init="contact = selOptions[0].value"></select>
<textarea ng-model="target"></textarea>
<a href="#" ng-click="shiftArr()"><img src="..." id="plusbutton"></a>
```

In the controller, initialize `$scope.target`, and modify `$scope.shiftArr`, as follows:

```
$scope.target = '';

$scope.shiftArr = function() {
    var arrVal = $scope.contact;
    var newArr = [];
    newArr = $scope.selOptions;
    for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        if (newArr[i].value === arrVal) {
            $scope.target = $scope.target + newArr[i].name + '\n'; 
            var index = arrVal - 1 ;
            newArr.splice(index, 1);
            $scope.temp = newArr;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: With this solution, no data in the below select options is forming http://plnkr.co/edit/ATq514K1be6oviJXIdod?p=preview